# Make kendo grid cell editable or read-only depending on other cell's state

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with inline editing. I want to be able to make one of the cells in the row editable if another cell in the row is checked. If it's not checked then I want the cell to be read-only.

My columns look like this:

```
columns: [
    { field: "Title" }, // string
    { field: "Body" }, // string
    { field: "IsCalculated", template: "#= IsCalculated ? 'Yes' : 'No' #" }, // boolean
    { field: "Expression" } // string
]
```

If `Calculated` is checked then I want `Expression` to be editable, otherwise, I want it to be read-only.

I have looked at the configuration docs for the kendo grid and I have experimented with the `columns.editable` function but as explained in the docs: "The JavaScript function executed when the cell/row is **about** to be opened for edit. The result returned will determine whether an editor for the column will be created."

I can use this function to determine whether the cell should be editable or read-only before it's opened but I want to be able to change it while the cell is open for editing and the `Calculated` checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll probably have to do two things: 1) Use the function you described to prevent the cell from being edited if the box isn't checked and 2) Watch calculated for changes and potentially call the grid's closeCell function if the box is unchecked (not sure what you want to have happen to any entered value at that point)

Answer (score 1):

Try preventing the [`edit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) event with [`cancelRow()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-cancelRow):

```
edit: function(e) {
    if (!e.model.IsCalculated &&
        $(e.container).find('input').attr("name") == "Expression") 
    {
        this.cancelRow();
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/imoRO)

**UPDATE** - Better condition:

```
if (!e.model.IsCalculated &&
    $(e.container).find('input[name="Expression"]').length) // <---
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/imoRO/2)